# Как вытащить данные вложенного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Посылаю в функцию массив, для дальнейшей обработки. В этом массиве есть вложенные массивы.

**Как мне вытащить значения по ключу вложенных массивов, например `staff_permission_notifi`?**

Массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_task] => 10285
            [timezone_plus] => 10800
            [vid_connection] => lead
            [id_connection] => 256840
            [title] => Уговорить на встречу 
            [description] => 
            [message_client] => 0
            [id_staff_contractor] => 2810
            [staff_permission_notifi] => Array
                (
                    [status_vk] => 0
                    [confirm_vk] => 0
                )

            [staff_method_notifi] => Array
                (
                    [status_email] => 1
                    [status_sms] => 1
                    [status_telegram] => 1
                    [status_vkbot] => 0
                )

            [staff_contact_notifi] => Array
                (
                    [phone_staff] => 89859767747
                    [email_staff] => rustam@zalogfond.ru
                    [id_contact_vk] => 0
                    [id_contact_tg] => 647035299
                )

            [time_rem] => 1551366000
        )
 )
```

Функция:

```
function TaskProcessor($arrTask) {

        foreach($arrTask as $taskValue) {

            $id .= $taskValue['id_task'].'|'.$taskValue['title'].'|'.$taskValue['time_rem'].'|'.$taskValue['staff_permission_notifi']['vk_status'].'<br>';
        }
        return $id;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$taskValue['staff_permission_notifi']['status_vk']
$taskValue['staff_permission_notifi']['confirm_vk']
```

Comment: черт, я дурак! Просто неправильно указывал ключ =))) по-этому такая конструкция у меня не работала

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arrTask as $taskValue) {
    foreach ($taskValue as $key => $values) {
        if (is_array($values)) { // Ну или сравнивать $key == 'staff_permission_notifi'
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                // $value - значения вложенных массивов
            }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: я немного не правильно написал! нужно именно ПО КЛЮЧУ вытащить нужные значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    "title" => "Rear Window",
    "director" => "Alfred Hitchcock",
    "year" => 1954
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "Full Metal Jacket",
    "director" => "Stanley Kubrick",
    "year" => 1987
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "Mean Streets",
    "director" => "Martin Scorsese",
    "year" => 1973
  )
);


print_r($arr[0][title]);    // вернет   Rear Window
print_r($arr[1][director]); // вернет   Stanley Kubrick
print_r($arr[1][title]);    // вернет   Full Metal Jacket
print_r($arr[2][year]);     // вернет   1973
```